# C3.js explodes when trying to draw large amount of data

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I am trying to draw a line chart with c3.js. I can create the chart, but once I hit 30K of data (data: JSON), the library explodes and kills my browser.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Explode is too vague. Can you edit your question with the error you get?

Comment: it becomes very slow and kills my browser (the chart never renders in the DOM)